# Usage of "take your gin and guns to Putney"

Tags: phrase-usage, contemporary-english

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XXII, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_22)

Passage 350

> “I beg your pardon,” he said once. “I am a gentleman, Mr. Carthew here is a gentleman, and we don't mean to do that class of business. Can't you see who you are talking to? Can't you talk sense? Can't you give us 'a dead bird' for a good traderoom?”
>
> “No, I don't suppose I can,” returned old Bostock; “not when I can't hear my own voice for two seconds together. It was gin and guns I did it with.”
>
> “**Take your gin and guns to Putney**!” cried Hadden. “It was the thing in your times, that's right enough; but you're old now, and the game's up. I'll tell you what's wanted nowadays, Bill Bostock,” said he; and did, and took ten minutes to it.
>
> Carthew could not refrain from smiling. He began to think less seriously of the scheme, Hadden appearing too irresponsible a guide; but on the other hand, he enjoyed himself amazingly. It was far from being the same with Captain Bostock.

Is the phrase "take . . . to Putney" or "*go* to Putney" used these days or is it obsolete?
And why was Putney, a district in southern London, used?

The Oxford English Dictionary quotes:

> **1863** Now, in the year 1845, telling a man to go to Putney was the same as telling a man to go to the deuce“
> <sub>H. Kingsley, *Austin Elliot*</sub>

Source: [OED](https://www.oed.com/search/advanced/Quotations?textTermText0=go%20to%20Putney&textTermOpt0=QuotText)

Comment: I used the OED (please have a look at "Source") but, as I said, I don't know if it is used nowadays, actually.

Comment: Apparently, it's RLS unique way of saying "[go to Putney on a pig](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_to_Putney_on_a_pig)“

Comment: Out of the context  :)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a clear answer. But I'm not as smart as you suppose because the OED says 1863 only and it isn't said if this phrase is used nowadays :)

Comment: Philphil, your source from 1863 says that it _had that meaning in 1845_, implying that it was already obsolete! Interestingly, my late father (b.1907) used to use "Well, I'll go to Putney on a pig!" as an expression of surprise - I suppose it was a euphemism for "I'll be damned!"

Comment: [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+to+Putney&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that "go to Putney" was in use in the early and late 19th century.

Comment: @WeatherVane - A lot of those examples seem to be the literal meaning, or dictionaries of slang.

Comment: @KateBunting one would suppose that the literal meaning isn't subject to idiomatic currency.

Comment: @WeatherVane - That's what I meant!

Comment: ... so the variation would be in the slang usage.

Comment: [Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/qbqjlhy)  -  *go to Putney (on a pig)! (also go to Pettigo!)*

Comment: Generally used with variations of hell or fuck (I've heard France and Falkirk), though Green offers several other variations. Green doesn't explain what Putney did to deserve this. There could be an interesting question here if it was upgraded.

Comment: I don't understand that: there is an interesting discussion about this question, there are five users involved, there are more than eighty views - nevertheless this question is downvoted. Are we in a dormitory? What sense does the question "There could be an interesting question here if it was upgraded" make '(the question is about **contemporary usage**!!!)? It's an enigma, isn't it?

Comment: I'm still stuck on the dead bird.

Comment: @ TimR - OED: "1892+1898 - Dead-bird, in Australia, a recent slang term, meaning ‘a certainty’. The metaphor is from pigeon-sh…
E. E. Morris, Austral English
dead-bird, n."  https://www.oed.com/search/advanced/Quotations?textTermText0=dead-bird&textTermOpt0=WordPhrase&quotDateFirstUse=all&page=1&sortOption=AZ

Comment: @philphil The OED has always taken me to the "please purchase a subscription" page when I've visited and tried to search. This time it let me see the quotations.